# FlexListViewWebpart + custom XSLT (MOSS 2007)

Tags: 2007, xslt

I am working as a sharepoint consultant for 2 months now. Recently graduated so everything is a bit new to me.

At the moment i am trying to figure out the flexlistviewwebpart, a webpart to allow the display of listitems from other sites on your site.

Read for details:
http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/porint/archive/2006/02/17/3837.aspx

Adding this webpart is easy. But i would like to use my own xslt. I can't seem to figure out how to do this...
I can write my custom xslt for a Content By Query Webpart, but not for this one... Nothing seems to work.
Everything i do results in the same thing... So it looks like he doesn't realy detect my xslt.

This is the code i use to test:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<html xsl:version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">
  <body>
TESTTEKST
  </body>
  </html>

<xsl:template name="Default" match="*" mode="itemstyle">

<xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
                <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
<a>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
</a>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When trying this i would expect to see "TESTTEXT" appear in the webpart... But its not showing up...

Does anyone have any knownlegde of this webpart?
Thanks in advance

Frederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i figured it out by downloading the source code and editing the standard xslt.
Sorry.